CLT for an insurance company
An insurance company has 1,000 individuals of the same age insured. The probability of death in a given year for each insured individual is 0.01. The insured pay an annual premium of 1,200 eur, and in the event of death, 80,000 eur is paid out to the beneficiary. What profit is the director of the insurance company able to guarantee to the board with a probability of 90%?
My attempt:
$n = 1000, \mathbb{P}(\text{death})=0.01, X_i = \text{[i-th person died]}$ - it is 0 with probablity 0.99 and 1 with probablity 0.01,
$$S = \sum_{i=0}^n X_{i} $$ (the amount of people that died)
$$ \mathbb{P}(1000 \cdot 1200 - 80000 \cdot S \ge k) \ge 0.9 $$
Then using CLT:
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{S - 1000 \times 0.01}{\sqrt{1000 \times 0.0099}}\right) \leq \frac{\left(\frac{1200000 - k}{80000} - 10\right)}{\sqrt{1000 \times 0.0099}} = \Phi\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1200000 - k}{80000} - 10\right)}{\sqrt{1000 \times 0.0099}}\right) $$
and we ask when is it >=0.9
After some time we get $k \le 77303$
The result should be however $k \ge$, not $k \le $ and I really do not know where I did a mistake.

As a courtesy to readers, please use MathJax to format mathematics in your question.

The model you are using for the future lifetime random variable is incorrect.  You seem to be using a Bernoulli distribution, but this does not correctly take into account the number of years a given insured lives and pays an annual premium.
In particular, consider a single insured.  Upon the effective date of the policy, they are charged a premium of $1200$, which they continue to pay at each policy anniversary, so long as they remain alive.  At the time of death, the beneficiary of the policy is paid $80000$.  So if the insured lives at least $67$ years, the insurer has earned at least $67 \cdot 1200 = 80400 > 80000$ in premiums (ignoring the time value of money), exceeding the death benefit.  But if the insured dies within $66$ years, the insurer loses money.
Consequently, it is prudent to model the (curtate) future lifetime random variable for a single insured as the whole number of years that they have paid the premium:  Let $K$ be this random variable, which has support $K \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  Then because the insured is assumed to have a $p=0.01$ probability of death in any given year, $$K \sim \operatorname{Geometric}(p = 0.01), \\ \Pr[K = k] = (1-p)^{k-1} p, \quad k \in \{1,2,3 \ldots \}.$$  We can easily check this makes sense:  the probability that the insured dies in the first year (hence the insurer receives only one year's premium), is $\Pr[K = 1] = (1-0.01)^{1-1} (0.01) = 0.01$.
Then the insurer's profit for a single insured is a random variable $$P = 1200K - 80000,$$ which represents the total premiums paid minus the death benefit (which of course is eventually paid).  As stated above, this random variable is negative if $K \le 66$, which represents a loss.
The total profit is therefore the sum of $n = 1000$ independent and identically distributed profits on each insured; i.e.,
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^{1000} P_i = -8 \times 10^7 + 1200 \sum_{i=1}^{1000} K_i$$ where each $P_i$ is distributed as $P$ and each $K_i$ is distributed as $K$.  For convenience, define $$\bar K = \frac{1}{1000} \sum_{i=1}^{1000} K_i$$ to be the sample mean of the number of insured-years of premiums paid.
The goal of the question is to determine the quantity $t$ such that
$$\Pr[T \ge t] = 0.90.$$
Since there are a large number of insureds,
$$\frac{\bar K - \operatorname{E}[\bar K]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\bar K]}}$$
is approximately standard normally distributed by the central limit theorem.  We compute
$$\operatorname{E}[\bar K] = \operatorname{E}[K] = 1/p = 100, \\
\operatorname{Var}[\bar K] = \frac{\operatorname{Var}[K]}{1000} = \frac{1-p}{1000 p^2} = 9.9.$$4
Hence
$$\begin{align}
0.90 &= \Pr[T \ge t] \\
&= \Pr\left[-8 \times 10^7 + 1.2 \times 10^6 \bar K \ge t\right] \\
&= \Pr\left[\bar K \ge \frac{t + 8 \times 10^7}{1.2 \times 10^6}\right] \\
&= \Pr\left[\frac{\bar K - 100}{\sqrt{9.9}} \ge \frac{\frac{t + 8 \times 10^7}{1.2 \times 10^6} - 100}{\sqrt{9.9}} \right] \\
&\approx \Pr\left[ Z \ge \frac{t - 4 \times 10^7}{360000\sqrt{110}}\right]
\end{align}$$
where $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$.  Since the $10^{\rm th}$ percentile of the standard normal is $z_{0.10} \approx -1.28155$, we require
$$\frac{t - 4 \times 10^7}{360000\sqrt{110}} = -1.28155,$$
or
$$t \approx 3.51612 \times 10^7.$$

It should be noted that the exact distribution of $1000\bar K$ is negative binomial, being the sum of $1000$ geometric distributions.  Specifically,
$$1000 \bar K = \sum_{i=1}^{1000} K_i \sim \operatorname{NegBinomial}(r = 1000, p = 0.01), \\
\Pr[1000 \bar K = k] = \binom{k - 1}{999} (0.99)^{k-1000} (0.01)^{1000}, \quad k \in \{1000, 1001, 1002, \ldots \}$$
so that $$0.90 = \Pr[T \ge t] = \Pr\left[1000 \bar K \ge \frac{t + 8 \times 10^7}{1200}\right].$$
Since the $10^{\rm th}$ percentile of such a negative binomial distribution is $95990$, we find
$$\frac{t + 8 \times 10^7}{1200} = 95990$$
or $t = 35188000$.  The exact probability is $$\Pr[T \ge 35188000] = 0.90000557413223895938\ldots.$$
